# Corresponding matrix for a symmetric non-degenerate bilinearform.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, bilinear-form

I am learning smth about the special orthogonal Lie Algebra. Therefore, I look at a symmetric non-degenerate bilinearform  
$ 
\begin{equation}
b : V \times V \to k,
\end{equation} 
$

where V is of dimension $2n$ and $k$ an algebraically closed field of characterisic zero. I want / need to show that there exists a basis $v_1, ... ,v_{2n}$, such that the corresponding matrix of b is of the form

$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & I_n\\
I_n & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$.

I tried to use induction, but did not know how to do it. I would be really happy if somebody can help me!

Comment: It is **not** true that there exists such a basis for every symmetric non-degenerate bilinear on a vector field over a field of characteristic zero, so there appears to be some information missing

Comment: @BenGrossmann: The question says the field is algebraically closed, and I believe the statement is true there.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I missed that, thanks

Comment: @JaZonk See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3792778/81360) for the result over $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all convince yourself that base change of a symmetric bilinear form corresponds to replacing the representing matrix $S$ by the matrix $P^TSP$, where $P \in GL_{d}(k)$ is the base change matrix between the two bases. The matrices $S$ and $P^TSP$ are called *congruent* to each other. Check that congruence defines an equivalence relation.

Over any field in which $2 \neq 0$, any symmetric matrix is congruent to a diagonal matrix. See [Will Jagy's exposition here, with many examples and links with more examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1388421/96384).

For example, check that your matrix $\pmatrix{0&I_n\\I_n&0}$ is congruent to $\pmatrix{2I_n&0\\0&-\frac12 I_n}$ via $P = \pmatrix{I_n&-\frac12I_n\\I_n&\frac12I_n}$.

Now a diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(d_1, ..., d_r)$ is congruent to $\mathrm{diag}(c_1^2d_1, ..., c_r^2d_r)$ via $P:=\mathrm{diag}(c_1, ..., c_r)$. In other words, we can change each of the diagonal entries by an appropriate square.

For example, over the field $\mathbb R$, the matrix $\pmatrix{2I_n&0\\0&-\frac12 I_n}$ is further congruent to $\pmatrix{I_n&0\\0& \color{red}{-} I_n}$ (and hence so is the original matrix $\pmatrix{0&I_n\\I_n&0}$: in the language of [Sylvester's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), the form we are looking at here when considered over a real vector space has signature $(n,n)$).

But of course over an algebraically closed field $k$ (or any field in which all elements are squares), we can just make all diagonal entries $=1$ or $=0$. And zeros occur if and only if the form is degenerate. In particular, up to base change there is only one non-degenerate symmetric bilinear forms over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $\neq 2$. In particular, the one you have there is it, since it is congruent to $\pmatrix{I_n&0\\0&I_n}$ (note it is congruent to the identity matrix over all fields in which $2$ and $-\frac12$ are squares).

Comment: Thank you, this make it clear for me!